# Limpiar RUT con expresiones regulares

Tags: c#, regex

El Rol Único Tributario en un identificador de *n* dígitos donde el ultimo elemento puede ser una letra k o K.

Necesito poder limpiar toda la cadena dejando solo los caracteres validos, por ejemplo:

```
12.345.678-9 -> 123456789
12345678k -> 12345678k
12asf345asf.,-´ñ6789 -> 123456789
123k456k789 -> 123465789
123k456k78k -> 12345678k
```

No logro hacer que funcione.
¿alguien me puede ayudar?

Saludos,

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, por favor realiza el [tour] para que conozcas mejor el funcionamiento del sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla] (https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges). Puedes agregar el código que has intentado usar? Revisa [ask]

Comment: no es mas facil y rapido revisar la cadena con un for hasta el anteultimo, y luego revisar el ultimo?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aplica esta expresión regular a cada línea:

```
[^0-9kK]+|[kK](?!\s*$)
```

de esta manera, deberías limpiar los caracteres inválidos.

Tienes una demo [aquí](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5E0-9kK%5D%2B%7C%5BkK%5D%28%3F!%5Cs*%24%29&i=12asf345asf.%2C-%C2%B4%C3%B16789KK%20%20%20%20%0D%0A&r=).

También una demo en javascript (simplemente para ver el funcionamiento) aquí abajo:

```js
const regex = /[^0-9kK]+|[kK](?!\s*$)/g;
const str = `12asf345asf.,-´ñ6789KK    `;
const subst = ``;

const result = str.replace(regex, subst);

console.log('Resultado de la sustitución: -->' + result + '<--');
```

Comment: Muchas gracias!!
Funciona perfecto :D

Comment: de nada! Si te sirvió puedes marcar la respuesta como "aceptada" Gracias. @Phipes

Comment: Muchas gracias!!! :D ¿Como hago eso de ponerla como aceptada?

Comment: Parece que ya lo hiciste, sale con el Tick verde. Gracias! Las respuestas se pueden votar y aceptar. Los votos sirven para denotar si la respuesta es de utilidad (aunque pudiera no responder al 100% a la pregunta), y el "aceptarlas" es para indicar que la respuesta soluciona la pregunta. Saludos.